# Check checkbox when textbox have specific number of characters

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, input

Hi im trying to make that my checkbox checked when the user type 8 digits on my input textbox. Now i can make the checkbox checked when te user types but im new in this and can't figure it out. THX for the help.

```
<input id="thecheckbox" type="checkbox">
<input id="theinput" type="text">

    $("#theinput").keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $("#thecheckbox").prop("checked", false);
    } else {
        $("#thecheckbox").prop("checked", true);
    }
});

$("#thecheckbox").change(function () {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#theinput").val("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `$(this).val() == ""` try using `$(this).val().length != 8`.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Yeah, I forgot to add the darn `.length` after pasting. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
$("#theinput").on('input', function () {
  if (this.value.length >= 8) {
    $("#thecheckbox").prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $("#thecheckbox").prop("checked", false);
  }
});

/* $("#thecheckbox").change(function () {
  if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("#theinput").val("");
  }
}); */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="thecheckbox" type="checkbox">
<input id="theinput" type="text">
```

Comment: This work here but I added to my code and don't work, I don't know it is something with my form. My full form code.

<form method="post" action="verifi.php" onkeypress="alerta(event)">
   <input id="thecheckbox" type="checkbox">
   <input id="theinput" type="text">
</form>

Comment: @JahlilEspinoza I did comment out the `.change()` code.  That would break it I think.  Otherwise, if you can replicate your code on http://jsfiddle.net, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: I replicate my code, here you can see it jsfiddle.net/hj9rss5g